# Displaying menu in all the activities without overriding onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected each time

Tags: android

While working with my application, I had to come to come across a situation where I supposed to use menu which has to get displayed in entire application when user click menu button. 
So I used following code in Default activity but then realized that menu is displaying in that activity but not in all.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.del_boy_menu, menu);
    //below comented code for changung dynamically
    // MenuItem bedMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.home);
    // bedMenuItem.setTitle("title changed");
    // System.out.println("onCreate executed");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("onOptionSelected executed");
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home:
            // Single menu item is selected do something
            // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
            Toast.makeText(MainDeliveryBoyActivity.this, "Home is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // MenuHomeActivity
            startActivity(new Intent(context,MenuHomeActivity.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.delivered1:
            Toast.makeText(MainDeliveryBoyActivity.this, "delivered is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.cancelled:
            Toast.makeText(MainDeliveryBoyActivity.this, "cancelled is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.active:
            Toast.makeText(MainDeliveryBoyActivity.this, "active is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So my question is should I copy and paste all the above code in all the activities? or is there a way where I can skip this?

Comment: Create a BaseActvity class and override its method and extend that activity in all your other activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one global activity called `BaseActivity` and make all of your activities extend it.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle iCreate){
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.del_boy_menu, menu);
        ....
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ....
    }
}
```

And now all other activities should extend the BaseActivity, so you won't need to write code to inflate menu everytime.

```
public class Activity1 extends BaseActivity{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Yeah it makes sense.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe each activity to have a unique menu. But there is a way you can do what you are trying to implement here.

- You can create a base class that inherits from an Activity class and put all your menu logic on that base class.

And you can also refer to this answer, [Reuse the Action Bar in all the activities of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889240/reuse-the-action-bar-in-all-the-activities-of-app) and [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html).

PS: I do not take credit for the answer, I just want to help. Cheers!