# Base Activity with HeaderBar

Tags: android

I created an android application, I have a BaseActivity this extends AppCompatActivity Activity and also I have other activity that all extends BaseActivity. My problem is to just one time create headerbar to admin as like toolbar but just one time call this headerbar in baseactivity and show in all other activity. I use toolbar but you must implement and set in all activity. 
[image]

Because when I login in app I want to name and photo show all activity but just only set image and photo and also bar in baseactivity. Its possible ?

Comment: headerbar? you mean toolbar?

Comment: No, toolbar must defined all activities

Comment: maybe this solution can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/17889581/4290472

Comment: no its not like my problem, I have a activity xml and this xml contain headerbar and content, And all other activities opened in this content.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base activity and extend all other activities from this base activity.

In base activity create a header and layout to store the children activitie's layout.

In child activities you can inflate layouts like this.

`getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child_activity_layout,childLayout);`

Comment: where is defined childLayout